# Can WcfTestClient.exe send content type 'application/soap+msbin1' request?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcftestclient, binary-xml

I'm trying to test a Silverlight WCF interface, by WcfTestClient.exe. However, I got below message from server:

HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'.
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 28 Oct 2014 18:13:30 GMT
Content-Length: 0

I can't change server configuration. Is there any work round on it?

Comment: can you provide how you are actually calling your wcf service?

Comment: The steps are simple: 1. open WcfTestClient.exe, 2. add service, 3. click the Invoke button. then error message come out: Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'